# Get array value by dynamic key in php

Tags: php

maybe I am totally blind but i have an array:

```
Array ( [p541] => 1 [p747] => 1 [p792] => 1 [p968] => 1 [p2157] => 1 [clickeditem] => 0WCr9ParDzLD9wpctknt0XErhOZcX33wXfgGDNpSoIo= [actualtime] => 11832 [timekey] => 1406227645 [actualuser_id] => V58yD4MQ2ZwTumjivhhQL/BSFXsu0Dvoj0bxp7Tu8PM= [timeout] => 0 [report_misuse] => 0 [A1] => 5RC52CZHPV8f0Zw+FYGZel5Ay2YcLVjrY8MBplz1zJA= [B1] => 0WCr9ParDzLD9wpctknt0XErhOZcX33wXfgGDNpSoIo= [B2] => KnCK/vIcQ5PAwJxjUMh0w+NTM+TqdVG9+Tiyi0U9QWM= [B3] => DhT8qBQFQC+dE/Rku7wdMJ4bw6dtFp8hzfmxPMCrItQ= [B4] => ZE30ASB6IUQglpXNiOUxdmiYpJnEbuKKXIaUZO9w4mU= [B5] => IXyGTO6V/8uZOK5y81DnI58xumZ0CIkFsTQwUWJ2CyE= [pageloadtime] => 0.179646 [option] => com_findme [view] => pair )
```

but I want to get the value for "p541"

```
$name= "p541";
$value = $array [$name];
```

does not work ???

Answer (score 0):

If your array variable is named `$array`, try this:

```
$value = $array['p541'];
```

---

What you're doing is creating a new array named `$value` containing the variable `$name`, which is not what we want.

Comment: sorry it was $value = array [$name];

Comment: Still - you're trying to create a new array. Unless you're missing a `$` in front of `array`. Does not my solution work?

Comment: Sorry again it is $value = $array [$name]; the problem is that i need to get the name "dynamic"

Comment: It should work. See this example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a13d976fe4b2cb079afdac7e06822bea3e6831ec. But I think your array is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your array items need to be comma separated and not within [ ] if you're declaring associative arrays like that. You also need to save your array to a variable so you can access it.

```
$value = array('p541' => 1, 'p747' => 2, 'p792' => 3);
```

then this...

```
$value['p541']
```

will equal 1